# Writing App to access text file on PC remotely possible?

Tags: android, ios

I am hopefully going to be embarking on producing a ios or android app that shows the x read of a till from a remote location over an internet connection. My question is wether it is possible to access a text file or xcel file, take the contents of the file and pull it to the app using android and ios? I have a way to get the x read to either a xls or txt file but need to know if I will be able to access it using a ios or android app?

Apologies for the basic explanation but I am quite new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You will have to write a server program that runs on the PC, and communicate via network sockets.

Comment: Thank you!!!! If you have a mo and have any specific advice please comment but you have given me the info I need to start researching

Comment: You're welcome! If this answer helped, please accept it by clicking the check mark to the left. Good luck for your project! Feel free to ask if problems arise along the way.

Comment: Checked it! Many thanks again I will have a tussle with it and let ya know!